# How can I stop a function from loading if a check box is ticked in GTK Python

Tags: python, gtk, glade, gedit

I am writing a program with a main menu, and several buttons that open different windows of the application. After the main menu pops up, I have rigged the code so that a popup window comes up right on top of the main menu. The popup tells you to visit the settings menu, and  gives you a checkbox that says "Don't show this window again". The idea is that if you tick that box, the popup will never popup again. The popup window is a function called reminder().
Early on in the program I call the reminder() function to get it to popup. The checkbox is linked to a function called reminder_toggled(). I need to know how I would write the reminder_toggled() function to make sure that the reminder() function does not run ever again. If any additional info is required just post a comment, I'll be checking this post every 5 minutes.

Thanks StackOverflow :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of calling `reminder_toggled()` function whenever the checkbox (say reminder_checkbox) is toggled, `reminder()` function should first check whether the reminder_checkbox is checked before executing further

```
def reminder():
    if reminder_checkbox.get_active():
        .
        .
        .
```

([get_active() documentation](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/ToggleButton.html#Gtk.ToggleButton.get_active))

Moreover, the reminder_checkbox's state should be stored in a config file on exit & loaded on startup of app.